# take a snapshot from wecam by using DShowNET library

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

how can i make a snapshot in my cod:

```
    using DirectX.Capture;
    using DShowNET;
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  DirectX.Capture.Capture capture = null;
    Filters filters = null;
capture = new DirectX.Capture.Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices[deviceNo], filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);

            capture.PreviewWindow = pictureBox1;
           }


 private void _Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
              //??
       }
```

i want to  convert pictureBox1's video stream to a image by clicking on "Pause" button.
and then save pictureBox1's pic(*.jpg) to data base.

Comment: By `DShowNET` you mean [`DirectShow.NET`](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), don't you? Then what is `DirectX.Capture` exactly? [This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library)?

Comment: yes Directx.capture is that page you told.and DShowNet is :http://dashingquill.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/capturing-webcam-using-directshow-net-library/

Comment: DirectShow is standard API, DirectShow.NET (link above) is popular open source wrapper over it, the two other you are using are almost unknown. If you chose to use them for some reason, you want to reference them every time directly because it is unclear what are they exactly.